# SQL Server management in VS2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, database-design

At university we have a server lab in which we do development using VS2012 for web modules such as ASP.NET. For such modules, we use Microsoft's SQL server.

My question is which extension in VS2012 would enable you to right click inside an 'open' table giving you options such as Check Constraints, Relationships etc.

I ask this because I have downloaded VS2012 to work on my own personal projects, but on opening a table and right clicking it, I receive an entirely different set of options, and I don't really want to write the SQL myself.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I have installed Sql Server 2012 with management tools etc on my machine here but not really sure what that's meant to achieve or how to integrate it into VS.

Comment: VS2012 has very limited SQL Server management capabilities - you're better off using the SQL Server Mgmt Studio. VS **2013** has a very much improved and much more powerful SQL Server management feature set.

Comment: If I didn't have Update 4 for VS2012 yet, would that explain my issue? I can change to VS2013 but I don't particularly want to if it isn't necessary.

Comment: No, Update 4 doesn't really bring any additional features - VS **2013** does!

Comment: VS Data Tools add-in allows you to modify tables and other objects from within VS2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx

Comment: I believe I have that, but what I've used in the labs was far, far more powerful. It included a GUI that enabled us to add check constraints, change foreign keys etc without typing out any SQL at all. It sort of reminded me of Oracle SQL Developer. Could it be Visual Database Tools?

Comment: It could be SQL Server Management Studio. Installed with the management tools. It is separate to and not integrated with Visual Studio.

Comment: Whatever I used was definitely integrated and it was definitely VS2012.